# \usepackage[hang]{subfigure} gives error message “please type a command or say end”

Tags: subfloats

I use the `\usepackage[hang]{subfigure}` so I can use `\makebox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm,left=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[main=english,portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[Portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[hang]{subfigure}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{image1}%
\hfill  [If you want some space between the images]  
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{image2}%
}%
\caption{Some long long caption}
\end{figure}

but in the same document I also use

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure #1}
        \caption{caption}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure #2}
        \caption{caption}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}
```

and get the log error message “please type a command or say end”. This error disappears if I erase the `\usepackage[hang]{subfigure}` from the preamble, but then I cannot use `\makebox`. I can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your document misses `\end{document}`.

Comment: My document has \end{document} I just forgot to mention it, I apologize. Anyhow, I changed the \package place in the preamble, moved it to the top, and it seemed to solve the problem:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm,left=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[hang]{subfigure}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[main=english,portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[Portuguese]{babel}


\begin{document}
...
\end{document}

Comment: Hmm... very strange. The error message you got is classically emmited when LaTeX reaches end of file without encountering `\end{document}`, hence switching to interactive console mode, waiting for the end of the file. I can't imagine how the position of a package call in the header can lead to that behaviour.

Comment: `subfigure` is an old, outdated package. Use `subfig` or `subcaption` instead!

Answer (score 1):

Running your example gives a few errors:

> *Option clash for package babel*

**Solution:**  Don't load `babel`twice.

> *Command \c@subfigure already defined.*

**Solution:** Don't load both `subcaption` and `subfigure`

> *File image1 not found.*

**Solution:** use `example-image-a` when posting on StackExchange as we don't have your images. These images are included in TexLive, so most people will have them.

> *Missing number, treated as zero. l.26 `\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}`*

**Solution:** As the syntax you are using is wrong, you should look up the propor syntax from the documentation: `\subfigure[⟨list entry⟩][⟨subcaption⟩]{⟨figure⟩}`

But as pointed out by *Christian Hupfer*, `subfigure` is outdated. I've used `subcaption` instead, which you already had loaded.

Also, you do not need any additional packages to use `\makebox`.

I will give you a tip though. As you seem confused by what each package does, you can write in you editor a short description, along with the package. For instance:

```
\usepackage{graphicx} % lets one include graphics, adds \scalebox and \rotatebox among other things
```

#### Output

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
\hfill % [If you want some space between the images]  
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
}%
\caption{Some long long caption}
\end{figure}

but in the same document I also use

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    %\subfigure[caption]{%
    \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \subcaption{caption}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \subcaption{caption}
    \end{minipage}
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```